# Object color search engine: Find physical objects of a particular color

Tags: gratis, web-apps, images, search-engine, color

I market a product with color #2A4095, and want to give it a product name using the name of an object that has the same color.

So, I want to find what objects (flowers, fruits, cloth, human objects) have color #2A4095 approximately.

The pictures could come from the Flickr set. The search engine's algorithm has to remove background/shade/reflections to estimate each object's actual color. It's rather difficult because several photography styles results in various kinds of color alterations.

For instance this should come for #d85133, not grey nor black nor white: [image: Fuji apple]

---

For this purpose I use [Multicolr](http://labs.tineye.com/multicolr), but it is far from perfect:

- It just takes the average color of a picture. A better tool would:

  - only process pictures that have a main object (ex: no drawings or landscape pictures)
  - detect the main object's contour, and don't take the color of the background into account.
  - don't take the object's shade and light reflection into account.
- It does not allow to search for #2A4095, only a few colors are available

[image: Multicolr color search]

Comment: Have you tried [PicItUp](http://www2.picitup.com/) tools?

Comment: Or [Palette](http://www.shutterstock.com/labs/palette/?pl=announcements-discanewkindofcoloba&cr=pb&image_type=photo&keyword=)? I noticed that searching for [search pictures with color](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+pictures+with+color) finds candidates

Comment: @JanDoggen: Palette has the exact same problems as Multicolr, see above.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Sorry my PicItUp comment was mistaken, removed. I tried the PicItUp tools too, none is a good solution: "Multicolor Flickr search" is the closest they have and it too has the exact same problems as Multicolr.

Comment: It **looks** like navy blue to me (http://www.colorhexa.com/2a4095) or not far from it. Why not just settle for searching for navy blue things? It seems much easier.

Comment: @Mawg: Several standard palettes use the name "Navy Blue", but none of them match my color. In fact, a Google Images search shows that "Navy blue" means VERY different colors for different people.

Comment: Sigh. I thought that it was too easy to be true. Is the theory correct? Find a named coloUr which is a near match to yours? Maybe not, since, as you say, people perceive coloUrs differently.   Hmmm, you might want to take that into consideration in your search - for instance, you have  2A red, would 28 or 2C be too far away from a match? Probably not. If you end up coding it yourself, allow some fuzziness on all 3 coloUrs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [python](http://python.org) to generate a histogram or each image with buckets of a given size, (the colour tolerance), about your desired colour then if the image contains more than a given percentage of the desired colour offer it up as a suggestion.

There are a number of python libraries that can create a histogram of an image, the bucket size would go some way to reducing the false rejects due to the style of photography and the threshold should try to reject images where a tiny area of the image matches.

You could possibly combine this with the python scapy library to mine images from a given site.